# The flag colouring problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Ok so I came across this question. It goes something like this : 
A new flag is to be designed with 6 vertical stripes using all 4 colours. In how many ways can this be done so that no 2 adjacent stripes have the same colour and it is given that we have to use all the 4 colours for 4 stripes ( we cannot use less than 4 colours to colour the stripes. For example, for a given set of colours {1,2,3,4}, the solution cannot be like 1,2,1,2,1,2). I've been struggling to come up with a solution. Can someone show me how it is done?

Comment: "all four colors for four strips".  Does that mean you can't do 1,2,3,4,3,2 because the middle four and the last four don't have the color 1?  If so that would mean the fifth and sixth strips must both be the same color as the first an second.

Comment: No. I mean that your above configuration must be present. By "all four colours for four strips" I mean that all the four colours must be used in a particular configuration. For example, the configuration 1,2,3,1,2 is not valid since you've not used the colour 4 anywhere but 1,2,3,4,3,2 is valid since you've used all the four colours atleast once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets forget about the restriction that we must use all four colours (i.e. we are now counting how many ways this can be done using **four or less** colours).

You then have $4$ choices for the first stripe.

Then $3$ choices for the second stripe (cannot be the same colour as the first stripe).

Similarly, $3$ choices for each of the following stripes.

Thus, there are $4 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 = 972$ combinations.

However, we must subtract the patterns that do not use all $4$ colours, so you ask yourself how many ways you can colour the flag with **three or less colours**, with no two adjacent stripes having the same colour.

There are $C_3^4 = 4$ ways of picking three colours out of four, and the number of patterns for the chosen set of colours is done using the above logic, giving $3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 96$ combinations.

It follows that we are left with $972-4 \times 96 = 588$ patterns.

However, as pointed out in the comments, the patterns that only use $2$ colours have been subtracted twice instead of just once, so we must add one set of these back in.

There are $C_2^4 = 6$ ways you can choose two colours out of four, and after you have selected two colours, there are only $2$ possible patterns (namely having the two colours alternating, or you can calculate $2 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 = 2$ like before). Thus, we must add back in $6 \times 2 = 12$ patterns.

In total, the answer is $972-4 \times 96 + 6 \times 2 = 600$ patterns.

Comment: But using the logic for three or less colours, aren't we limiting ourselves to only 3 colour choices for the first strip? Since we could have arrangements like 4,1,2,1,2,1 or 3,1,2,1,2,1 or 2,1,2,1,2,1 or 1,2,1,2,1,2. So we could also have 4 colours for the first strip

Comment: In the logic for three colours, I mean that you FIRST pick your three colours (say you decide you are only going to use $\{1,2,3\}$) THEN you decide on how you colour the flag. Sorry for my error

Comment: Yep that logic is right now. Thanks for the help.